# Best way to remotely access Linux VMs in VMware vCloud Director

Tags: vmware-vcloud-director

I'm very confused about how to remotely connect to my linux remote VMs on vCloud and none of the VMWare documentation is helping. I have access to a new vCloud through VMWare vCloud director. This is provided through a hosting company so I don't own the infrastructure but I have access to the vCloud portal. I've configured vApp networks, vApps, and I have 2 VMs running CentOS.

So, I want to either VPN/ssh into my virtual machines or something similar. But the only option is a popout console, which is just a popup window with console access.

[example of vCloud director options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SukBZ.png)

So I figure maybe I can configure a VPN to tunnel directly into the vApp network, but no, the only configuration I can find is site-to-site VPN connections and can only connect to the org-network.

I must be missing something completely obvious?

Comment: have you considered having your VPN server running in your local environment and making the VMs clients? What is the hosting service, do they have another product that provides VPN functionality at an additional cost?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered that. I would still need to have each of my developers run a VPN server on their local machines if I flipped the model like that. For now, I'm going to enable direct outside access to the internet on ssh ports for these machines, since I don't have too many options.

Comment: hmm, sounds like there's no centralized office so setting up all those vpn connections wouldn't really be sustainable. can your vms access each other?